# Make from polygon the clockwise polygon

Tags: polygon

I know how to determine if polygon is clockwise(compute the area and compare with 0. If area > 0 then polygon is clockwise). 
If polygon isn't clockwise then how to convert it to clockwise polygon?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question might be interesting, but not appropriate. Read the [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what you can ask here. Show some research effort and try something, and if you don't succeed you can ask specific questions about problems you are facing with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just inverse order of vertices.  If you pave polygon with vertices v1, v2, ..., vN and it is not clockwise, than polygon vN, ..., v2, v1 will be clockwise.